Langgraph tools_condition prebuilt method routing to other nodes instead of END node
I was building quite a simple graph using Langgraph. I decided the pre-built tools_condition function from langgraph. So I imported it and used it as follows:
graph_builder = StateGraph(State)
graph_builder.add_node("chatbot", assistant)
graph_builder.add_node("tools", lambda state: run_tool(state, tools={"athena_query":athena_query}))
graph_builder.add_node("report_checker", report_check)

graph_builder.add_edge(START, "chatbot")
graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
    "chatbot",
    tools_condition
)
# graph_builder.add_edge("chatbot", "tools")
graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "chatbot")
graph_builder.add_edge("chatbot", "report_checker")

graph = graph_builder.compile(checkpointer=memory)

The resulting graph is the following:

It does not make sense that there is a conditional edge pointing from assistant to report_checker when I specify that it is a regular edge. Why is the default behaviour of tools_condition to make conditional edges to everything else if its not a tool call and not just go to END?
I know this because if I pass the routing arguments of where it is supposed to go, the extra conditional edges disappear:
graph_builder = StateGraph(State)
graph_builder.add_node("chatbot", assistant)
graph_builder.add_node("tools", lambda state: run_tool(state, tools={"athena_query":athena_query}))
graph_builder.add_node("report_checker", report_check)

graph_builder.add_edge(START, "chatbot")
graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
"chatbot",
tools_condition,
{
    "END": END,
    "tools": "tools", 
}
)
graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "chatbot")
graph_builder.add_edge("chatbot", "report_checker")

graph = graph_builder.compile(checkpointer=memory)

The unwanted conditional edge is now gone:

Why is default tools_condition routing the main node somewhere other than the END node?

Did you ever resolve this?

Not sure I exactly follow your issue, but here is a simple example I have that routes to tools while the engineer makes tools calls and when its done it ends.
graph = StateGraph(ProjectState)
graph.add_node("tools", ToolNode(tools))
graph.add_node("sql_engineer", sql_engineer)
graph.add_node("sql_evaluator", sql_evaluator)

graph.add_edge(START, "sql_engineer")
graph.add_conditional_edges("sql_engineer", tools_condition, ["tools", END])
graph.add_edge("tools", "sql_evaluator")
graph.add_edge("sql_evaluator", "sql_engineer")

app = graph.compile()

