Langraph - tools_condition - conditional edge
I am new to langgraph (python) and trying to go through some examples found in Langgraph pages.
My code looks like below:
class State(TypedDict):
    summary: str
    messages: list

def summarize_conversation(state: State):
    # First, we summarize the conversation
    summary = state.get("summary", "")
    if summary:
        # If a summary already exists, we use a different system prompt
        # to summarize it than if one didn't
        summary_message = (
            f"This is summary of the conversation to date: {summary}\n\n"
            "Extend the summary by taking into account the new messages above:"
        )
    else:
        summary_message = "Create a summary of the conversation above:"

    messages = state["messages"] + [HumanMessage(content=summary_message)]
    response = model.invoke(messages)
    return {"summary": response.content, "messages": messages}

graph_builder = StateGraph(State)
graph_builder.add_node("tools", ToolNode(tool_set))
graph_builder.add_node("chatbot", lambda state: {"messages":assistant_runnable.invoke(state)})
graph_builder.add_node("summarize_conversation", summarize_conversation)
graph_builder.add_edge("tools", "summarize_conversation")
graph_builder.add_edge("summarize_conversation", "chatbot")
graph_builder.add_conditional_edges(
    "chatbot", tools_condition
)
graph_builder.set_entry_point("chatbot")
graph = graph_builder.compile()

The trouble is I get this extra conditional edge from Chatbot node to "summarise_conversation" node. Why is this and how do i remove this ?

PS : For brevity I have not included the full code.

what is tools_condition here?

@cottontail  - https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/reference/prebuilt/#tools_condition its a prebuilt condition edge that can be used to connect a "chatbot" and "Tool Node".

There must be some other code to define the graph that is not shown here that is causing the conditional edge. Your code as is shouldn't have that because the prebuilt tools_condition can only return "tools" or "__end__".

@cottontail - i agree - and i look at the source code of that tools_condition - https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/reference/prebuilt/?h=tools+condition#tools_condition but no luck. also realised yesterday that someone else had the same qn asked 4 days earlier than mine.. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79003055/langgraph-tools-condition-prebuilt-method-routing-to-other-nodes-instead-of-end
